# Why am I an unknown vendor?

Tags: google-chrome-app, hid

My company has a registered USB vendor ID (VID), so I don't see why I'm showing up as an 'unknown vendor' when a user goes to install my app through the chrome web store:

[image]

In my mainfest.json:

```
"hid",
{
  "usbDevices": [
    {"vendorId": XXXX,"productId": YYYY}
   ]
},
```

Where are known vendors pulled from?  Is there another area of the chrome developer dashboard I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Chrome executable contains an embedded list of USB vendors. The source of this list is visible at:

http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/third_party/usb_ids/usb.ids

It looks as though the version in the Chromium source hasn't been updated in a few years, so recently registered vendor IDs may not be present. First make sure your vendor ID is present in the master list (http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids), then poke someone on the Chromium project to update to an appropriate version of the list. (You're probably not the only newly registered vendor to go missing, so updating the list will help more people than just yourself.)